# R - How to make choose.dir() use windows file explorer like choose.files( )

Tags: r, windows, sharepoint

I'm working on a project where I need to build functions where users select the input file with choose.files( ) and select an output folder. I've been trying to use choose.dir( ) to do the folder selection. The main issue I have is that I need them to be able to select a synced sharepoint folder for an output. Choose.file( ) open windows file explorer which i can select the synced folders, meaning getting the data is fine.

However, choose.dir( ) opens the R Browse for Folder explorer which doesn't seem able to view these synced folders. Is there a method for making choose.dir( ) use the windows file explorer in the same way as choose.files( ) or are there other method for choosing a directory which the user might be able to "see" the synced sharepoint folders?

Key information from session info which might help:

sessionInfo()

R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)

Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Comment: tcltk::tk_choose.dir() does work thank you, if you'd like to add it as an answer I can mark it as accepted. For anyone else who comes across this. The resulting directory explorer doesn't always appear as your front window so you'll have to minimise/look around for it. also wont appear as an item of the taskbar so you cannot navigate to it from there.

Comment: Have transferred my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be:

```
tcltk::tk_choose.dir()
```

Also perhaps look into the rChoiceDialogs package.